# logical sentences and quantifiers

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

We are given a sentence and told to write the quantifier statement that corresponds with it. I had a similar question like this the other day, but this one goes the opposite way.

Let $B(x)$ mean $x$ is a bird, $W(x)$ mean $x$ is a worm, and $E(x, y)$ mean $x$ eats $y$.

We are told to give the statement for the sentence "Not all birds eat worms." Here is what I am thinking so far:

1. $\exists x(B(x) \rightarrow \forall y(W(y) \land \lnot E(x, y)))$

I am not sure if this is the correct statement or not. What I think my answer says is, "There exists a bird such that for all worms, the bird does not eat worms." Since there exists a bird that does not eat worms, doesn't that satisfy the sentence "Not all birds eat worms"?

I also came up with another idea but I'm not sure which one is right:

2. $\exists x \forall y(B(x) \land W(y) \rightarrow \lnot E(x, y))$

Which one is correct? (If any of them are) Both make a lot of sense to me which is why I don't know which one is it. The second one to me says, "There is a bird as for all worms such that the bird does not eat worms." Any help on going about solving these types of problems?

Answer (score 1):

Your first answer isn't quite correct. It says "There is a thing such that if it is a bird, then for all objects $y$, $y$ is a worm and $x$ doesn't eat $y$". That isn't what you meant to say: I, for instance, satisfy that predicate.

The second attempt has the same problem: let $x$ be me. Then the predicate is satisfied because $B(x)$ is never true.

"Not all birds eat worms" is "there is an object which is a bird and which does not eat worms", or "there is an object which is a bird, and such that for all objects which are worms, the bird-object doesn't eat the worm-object".

Comment: How would I go about interpreting this then? "There is an object which is a bird and which does not eat worms" so: $\exists x \forall y(B(x) \land W(y) \land \lnot E(x, y)). Forgive me, I don't know how to do LaTex in the comments.

Comment: @GenericUser01 You did just fine, except you omitted the closing \$. LaTeX mostly works in comments just as it does in posts (at least here and some few other sites)..

Comment: @GenericUser01 That's not quite right either: you're saying that there is a bird and also all objects are worms which are not eaten by the bird. It's helpful to separate your quantifiers so that you're only talking about one of them at a time: $\exists x: (B(x) \land \forall y: (W(y) \Rightarrow \neg E(x, y)))$